# Laravel 5.3 get Data of relational database table

Tags: php, laravel-blade, laravel-5.3

I got 2 Tables in my Database
First Table: "appointments" with the columns Id & userid
Second Table: "users" with the columns id & name

with blade I can easily show all appointments, but I want to show the users name & not only the id. So when I loop it with blade I could easy show the data with `{{ $appointment->userid }}`
But how can I get now for this appointment, the Users Name?

Comment: If you define your eloquent relationships you can use those to get the user from the Appointments Model: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships

Comment: In you controller fetch the users with your appointments `Appointments::with('users')->all()` asuming that you have a `users` relationship in your Appointments Model !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define a relationship in your `appointment` class as:

```
public function user()
{
   return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'userid');
}
```

Then in your blade you can do as:

```
{{ $appointment->user->name }}
```

[Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships)